# Как определяют реальный IP адрес запроса?

Tags: php, парсер, curl

У меня есть парсинг , реализованный через curl . Я использую мобильные прокси через https.
На одном сервере запускаю парсинг и он работает, а на другом запускаю - нет (блокировка).
Подскажите, каким образом сайт, который парсят, определяет с какого ip-адреса идет парсинг , ведь используется прокси ?

JS не работает,
Прокси стоят одинаковые (мобильные),
Условия работы парсинга одинаковые, за исключением ip-сервера, на котором он находится.
1 сервер - россия
2 сервер - беларусь

Comment: В смысле с какого? В PHP - $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. Это же сетевой запрос, следовательно на сервере можно получить адрес клиента. Он не получает ваш адрес если запрос делается с прокси (только в том случае когда прокси сам передает это в заголовке)

Comment: вы пишите тривиальные вещи. Тут ни REMOTE_ADDR, ни в заголовках ничего нет от реального ip

Comment: Потому что это тривиально по своей сути, но без знания того что передает прокси вы не сможете понять передает ли он ваш реальный адрес, или нет. Если да - то он будет в заголовке, если нет - то конечный сайт не узнает вашего реального адреса. Вполне может быть что сайт блокирует прокси.

Comment: ну вот у меня два сервера, на каждый сервер закидываю одинаковый скрипт и одинаковые прокси. На одном работает, на другом нет . 
 Я даже создал тестовый третий сервер, и к нему начал делать обращения, чтобы читать данные из _SERVER, но там нет ничего такого, что  показало бы,что стоит позади прокси . 


Я подумал, может сайт как-то определяет с какого домена идет обращение, но тоже непонятно как .

Answer (score 0):

Это может быть двусторонний пинг, т.к сервера находятся в разных локациях

Запустив пинг к клиентскому IP, со стороны нашего сервера, можно узнать приблизительную длинну маршрута. То же самое можно сделать со стороны браузера, XMLHTTPRequest дёргает пустую страницу нашего nginx. Полученную разницу в петле более 30 мс можно интерпретировать как туннель.

https://habr.com/ru/post/263557/

Comment: но так и непонятно, почему на одном сервере работает , а на другом - нет. Ведь прокси и там и там одинаковые прописаны

Comment: Разная удаленность серверов от сервера объекта парсинга, соответственно и разный пинг

Comment: так в данном случае, что лучше делать-то, не совсем ясно ?

Comment: Запретил доступ к серверу через iptables, но это не помогает

Comment: Можно попробовать:

Добавьте следующую строку в «/etc/sysctl.conf» 
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 1
либо
sudo bash -c 'echo "net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
затем применить изменения
sudo sysctl -p

Comment: все верно,  я так и делал . Он не пингуется. Но на возможность парсинга это не повлияло ((

Answer (score 0):

В свое время я защищался от хождения и граббинга моих сайтов в несколько потоков через прокси двумя путями.
`1)` Через `crontab` опрашивал популярные форумы и сайты где выкладывают бесплатные прокси. На их основе создавал `ban`-list в `iptables`
`2)` В момент прихода на мою страницу посетителя выполнял нехитрые действия

```php
$isProxy = false;
$proxyPortsList = [8080,8081,3128,81,88 ... ...];
foreach( $proxyPortsList as $port) {
    $userIP = getENV('REMOTE_ADDR');
    $fp = fsockopen( $userIP, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if ( $fp ) {
        $isProxy = true;
        fclose($fp);
    }

}
if ( $isProxy ) {
    header('Location: https://google.com');
}
```

В 90% случаев помогало. :)

Так что, вполне может быть что-то из этого использует и сервер на который Вы ходите.